# how to save map tile by lat long bounds for offline use?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, maptiler

I have a routing application that I want to put offline map of cities of my country for download, so that users of their city will download that map and use it as a offline.
The process of storing the map is as follows to allow the user to select a bound (the northest latlng and the southest latlng) and the zoom value and download  favorite map from Google.

[image]

Comment: The android google maps api does not have this ability

Answer (score 1):

Like is said in this [post](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?hl=en&visit_id=1-636549920880210546-563515714&rd=1):

You will need to provide the map area download to app users, save it somewhere in the app folder and then use the map offline. In another case, it would work only if they had a saved area already.

I guess that in your case, as the user would need internet connection it can use the API directly, it is just a pré-requirement.

Comment: I mean, but you don't want an image right? you want the all API with directions, zoom, etc, right?

Comment: have you an account of telegram ?

Comment: No and then I did not understand your anwser, if it is a static image just save it and use it as an ImageView.

Comment: I want what we do in google maps like this [link](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?hl=en&visit_id=1-636549920880210546-563515714&rd=1)
user do in my app

Comment: But as I said, people would need internet connection to download, so if is the case they can use the map online. If you want that map zone only you can set bounds in map using the LatLngBounds.
Otherwise it only work if they had the map area already on the phone.

Comment: my main question is how to save custom tiles of google map in my storage?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can do it on the app itself, just google a bit ;)